# Building to iOS from Cordova Tools using old version of iOS platform

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

When targeting iPhone 6 as my simulator the incorrect splash screen is loaded which is forcing the WebView to upscale.

I can navigate into the cordova project on OSX in the remote-builds folder which allows me to discover that the iOS platform version cordova is using is 3.6.3, where the latest is 3.7 which has the fixes for iOS8 and splash screens for iPhone 6.

I need to be able to tell the remote agent to use the new platform to build, not the old one. Is that even possible? Do I need to wait for a new version of the remote agent / cordova tools for VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to manually update the Cordova version in Visual Studio is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx#ThirdParty). Refer the section "To update vs-mda-remote on your Mac to a different version of Cordova". Please note that Visual Studio CPT3.0 support Cordova CLI 4.0.0, you can find more info on CPT3.0 [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs)

Comment: Thanks ! ... char limit