# Set an iPhone 6 launch image on Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

We are using CTP 3 of VS extension for Cordova.
We are trying to add a splash screen for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. We need this to solve and issue where iPhone 6+ resolution is incorrect within the app.
Is there a naming convention for the splash screen files for ios?
We know these file names are being added to the XCode project and work successfully (in res\screens\ios):

- screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png
- screen-ipad-landscape.png
- screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png
- screen-ipad-portrait.png
- screen-iphone-568h-2x.png
- screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png
- screen-iphone-portrait.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up forcing vs-mda-remote to use cordova 4.2.0 which helped solve the problem (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137528/building-to-ios-from-cordova-tools-using-old-version-of-ios-platform)).
Then we added this to the config.xml and the respective files.

```
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
  </platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are the naming conventions for iPhone6 and 6plus:

```
res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png (180x180) 
res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png (750x1334) 
res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png  (1242x2208) 
res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png (2208x1242)
```

Comment: We tried adding this file: **screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png  (1242x2208)** and had no success. The file is copied through to the mac but it's not showing up with the other images in platforms/ios/[Project]/Resources/splash